# Hide() in jquery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Code in index.html

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="loadIndex()">
<a id="registration" href="register.html"> Register </a>
</body>
```

Code in index.js

```
function loadIndex() {
alert("Page is loaded");
$("#registration").hide();
}
```

I get alert, but link is not hidden. I have more files, and this does not work in any of them. I think that mistake is not in code, but I don't know where is.

Comment: You're missing the closing `</head` tag

Comment: Is `onload` too early for jQuery?  Aren't you supposed to do this via `$(...)` ?

Comment: I don't think so, w3schools suggest to put onload in body tag

Comment: Why don't you actually use jquery ? $(document).ready(function(){  will do on page load

Comment: Are you sure you're referencing jquery.min.js correctly? Can you open your console and confirm you don't have an error like: scripts.js:4 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at loadIndex (scripts.js:4)
    at onload ((index):6)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is fine with the exception of a tiny syntax issue. You're just missing the closing tag `</head>`. Check code below:

```js
function loadIndex() {
  alert("Page is loaded");
  $("#registration").hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="loadIndex()">
  <a id="registration" href="register.html"> Register </a>
</body>
```

Comment: I made mistake while copy/paste. I closed </head>.

Comment: Did that fix your issue?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? My guess is there is an issue with the link to your jQuery script since your issue is with the one real line of jQuery in your code. Are you sure your `src` is pointing to the correct location?

Comment: I don't have any errors in console. jquery.min.js is in js folder, so path is good I think...

Comment: Add this line of code as the first line of your `loadIndex()` function:   `console.log(window.jQuery ? "jQuery lib found" : "jQuery NOT found");` The console.log should tell you if that's your real issue.

Comment: jquery.min.js 404 (Not Found) , but i have that file... i dont understand

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this setup:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
       alert("Page is loaded");
       $("#registration").hide();
     });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <a id="registration" href="register.html"> Register </a>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't work for me, i don't understand what is wrong with this project.

Comment: This works entirely in jsFiddle so it's something you're not showing us. What is in index.js? Also check your script imports are actually working

Comment: I don't have any errors in console. jquery.min.js is in js folder, so path is good I think...

Comment: Try using hosted jquery libraries for testing to make sure it isn't that. Because it's either that or index.js because that works in jsfiddle.net

Comment: Even if I put <script> tag in  index.html i don't get result... so it is not about index.js...

Comment: @tudomovv check if in console its throwing any error, else put break point after alert and in console type $("#registration").hide(); I think your jquery path is not correct. If you type $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#registration").hide();
}); it will throw error

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with `jQuery v1.11` before, I solved this problem by creating new class in my css file as below :

```
.hidden {
  display : none;
}
```

and for show and hide elem, I added and removed hidden class from elem.

hide: `$(elem).addClass('hidden');`

show:  `$(elem).removeClass('hidden');`